# Can't choose to boot to Windows 7 after Windows XP installation

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Error loading operating system” after installing Windows XP on separate partition from Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/92058/error-loading-operating-system-after-installing-windows-xp-on-separate-partiti)

I had Windows 7 installed on my existing Windows XP Pro, which used to give me option to choose the OS whenever the computer was switched on.

Now I reinstalled XP and my system boots only to XP and does not show the boot manager to choose either Windows 7 or Windows XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are adding OS installations to a multiboot system, the last install usually writes over the previous boot manager like this. Ideally you should install the OS with the boot manager you prefer last.
But in cases like this, you can just repair the boot manager. For the Windows 7 boot manager, [this page has a nice tutoria](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html)l.

Comment: Though late in replying, this solution worked for me...Thanks